# Design does not finish synthesizing after 4 hours

Tags: vhdl

In my design I have a matrix of 1024 integers. Under certain circumstances, I need to increase the value of some of these integers in a unit. The problem is that I cannot make this design finish synthesizing, I have waited more than four hours and it still does not end or returns an error.

Previously I had a code that synthesized in a few minutes, but when I added this (actually a very similar one), he spent more than 12 hours synthesizing and never finished.

I hope you can help me, I am finishing my degree work and I have not been able to finish it because of this problem.

Thank you

The design is as follows:

````
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;
use IEEE.NUMERIC_STD.ALL;

entity Proof_Array is
  Port (
    reset                  :   in  std_logic;
    Peak_height_detected_1 :   in  std_logic_vector(9 downto 0);
    Add_this_height        :   in  std_logic;
    S_clk_ADC_15MHz        :   in  std_logic;
    S_Out                  :   out std_logic_vector(31 downto 0));
end Proof_Array;

architecture Behavioral of Proof_Array is
    type PHA_Array_Type is array (0 to 1023) of integer;
    signal PHA_Array: PHA_Array_Type;
    signal number: integer range 0 to 1023;

    signal Peak_height_detected_1_int: integer range 0 to 1023;
begin
    Peak_height_detected_1_int <= to_integer(unsigned(Peak_height_detected_1));
    S_Out <= std_logic_vector(to_unsigned(PHA_Array(number), S_Out'length));

    process(reset, S_clk_ADC_15MHz)    
    begin
        if reset = '1' then 
            for k in 0 to 1023 loop 
                PHA_Array(k) <= 0; 
            end loop;
        elsif rising_edge(S_clk_ADC_15MHz) then
            if Add_this_height = '1' then
                PHA_Array(Peak_height_detected_1_int) <= PHA_Array(Peak_height_detected_1_int) + 1;
            end if;
            if number > 1022 then 
                number <= 0;
            else 
                number <= number + 1;
            end if;
        end if;    
    end process;```
````

Comment: This is a hardware design issue and not a VHDL programming problem. Consider asking on [Electrical Engineering Stack Exchange](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/vhdl).

Comment: Adding the missing library clause and architecture end statement, and the code analyzes. Without knowing the target device or synthesis vendor a memory won't have an asynchronous reset, implying 1024 x 32 D flip flops, 1 of 1024 steering selection for write and 32 1024:1 output selectors for read. The number of flip flops and any timing constraints could be giving the synthesis tool heartburn. It may be possible to use a memory array if you write 0 individually to all locations during a lengthened reset interval.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't say what tool you are using for synthesis, or even whether the target device is an FPGA, ASIC or something else. However, the short answer is that I think you will probably be able to achieve what you are trying to do - but I think the key will be finding a way to implement `PHA_Array` as a RAM.

Assuming you are targeting an FPGA, it is likely that you must impose (at least) the following restrictions in order to infer a RAM:

1. Address a maximum of 2 entries of `PHA_Array` simultaneously (whether reading, writing or both, at each address).
2. When reading, the integer must be registered at least 1 time before modifying (+1).

Currently, the 1st condition is violated when you clear the whole of `PHA_Array` in parallel during reset. The 2nd condition is violated when you immediately increment the integer in the same cycle that it is read (and written back).

There is no quick answer to how to fix this, as the best answer depends on your requirements. However, a huge simplification would be if you could **guarantee** that `Add_this_height` is never asserted on consecutive clock cycles. If this is the case, then you might try something like this:

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;
use IEEE.NUMERIC_STD.ALL;

entity Proof_Array is
  Port (
    reset                  :   in  std_logic;
    Peak_height_detected_1 :   in  std_logic_vector(9 downto 0);
    Add_this_height        :   in  std_logic;
    S_clk_ADC_15MHz        :   in  std_logic;
    S_Out                  :   out std_logic_vector(31 downto 0));
end Proof_Array;

architecture Behavioral of Proof_Array is
    type PHA_Array_Type is array (0 to 1023) of integer;
    signal PHA_Array: PHA_Array_Type;

    signal Add_this_height_r    : std_logic;

    signal RamWrEnA : std_logic;
    signal RamAddrA : unsigned(9 downto 0);
    signal RamOutA  : integer;

    signal RamWrEnB : std_logic;
    signal RamAddrB : unsigned(9 downto 0) := (others => '0');
    signal RamOutB  : integer;

begin

    PortA_proc : process(S_clk_ADC_15MHz)
    begin
        if rising_edge(S_clk_ADC_15MHz) then
            -- Cycle 1 - Record which address to update
            Add_this_height_r <= Add_this_height;
            if Add_this_height = '1' then
                RamAddrA <= unsigned(Peak_height_detected_1);
            end if;

            -- Cycle 2 - Read from RAM
            RamWrEnA <= Add_this_height_r;
            RamOutA <= PHA_Array(to_integer(RamAddrA));

            -- Cycle 3 - Write to RAM (assuming RamAddrA hasn't changed)
            if RamWrEnA = '1' then
                PHA_Array(to_integer(RamAddrA)) <= RamOutA + 1;
            end if;
        end if;
    end process;

    -- Assuming reset is synchronized to S_clk_ADC_15MHz
    RamWrEnB <= reset;

    PortB_proc : process(S_clk_ADC_15MHz)
    begin
        if rising_edge(S_clk_ADC_15MHz) then
            -- Always loop this address
            RamAddrB <= RamAddrB + 1;

            -- Clear in reset
            if RamWrEnB = '1' then
                PHA_Array(to_integer(RamAddrB)) <= 0;
            end if;
            -- Read to output
            RamOutB <= PHA_Array(to_integer(RamAddrB));
        end if;
    end process;

    S_Out <= std_logic_vector(to_unsigned(RamOutB, S_Out'length));

end Behavioral;
```

This works by using RAM port "A" to do the Read-Modify-Write part, and RAM port "B" to do the reading out and clearing in reset parts.

Note again that this assumes `Add_this_height` is **never** high on 2 consecutive cycles. Even if this assumption is incorrect, you could try synthesizing this code. If it synthesizes relatively quickly, then that at least implies that inferring a RAM may be a good way forward.

Comment: ***There is no quick answer to how to fix this, as the best answer depends on your requirements.*** For example Xilinx supports [Distributed RAM using LUTs](https://www.xilinx.com/products/intellectual-property/dist_mem_gen.html) to construct larger memories on some FPGA devices. These can have asynchronous read and a single address port. The performance is dependent on the number of words (16–65,536) and widths (1-1024) bits. The point is without the design requirements you can't help the question's author with the design. It belongs in a forum supporting hardware design in any event.

Comment: Obviously Oldfart and I both think we can help, otherwise we wouldn't have posted answers. Yes, different devices contain different stuff; I have not optimized my answer for an unknown device. The question was about extremely long compilation times, so I attempted to provide an answer that is likely to help with that (regardless of whether more exotic RAM types are available or not).

Comment: Synthesis times, not compilation. The VHDL analyzes and elaborates (compiles) in seconds. See [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) ...**Answer [well-asked](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) questions**, "Not all questions can or should be answered here. ... Save yourself some frustration and avoid trying to answer questions which... • ...are not about programming as [defined in the help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)." Review queue moderation and meta.stackoverflow can teach asking and answering guidelines and reasoning.

Comment: I'm sorry if I have violated Stack Overflow's conditions. I thought it was an interesting problem and thought I could help. This is apparently welcome everywhere else on Stack Exchange, but worthy of a barrage of hostility here under the `vhdl` tag. I'm not sure that policing the answers so harshly is helping anyone.

Comment: Guidelines not conditions, everything depends on question quality, SO is supposed to be search resource. You can help improve questions by moderation as reputation increases or by encouraging question improvements through comments). Here no actual question, just an off topic problem. Can that be changed? User dynamics are [well understood](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251758/why-is-stack-overflow-so-negative-of-late/252077#252077). (Everyone is uncomfortable with the chart and fulfills different roles with different goals over time, it's a manufactured state of tension.)

Answer (score 1):

Not only do you have 1024 32-bit wide registers, you also have 1024 32-bit adders for incrementing plus a condition which one to increment.

This is A LOT of logic and I would recommend to reduce it. It is unlikely that this will fit in your FPGA and even it it does it might use too many resources.

The first reduction is: do you really need to be able to count to 2147483647?
Also you are using an integer which can be negative but I think you don't need the negative part. So I would suggest you first set a count limit and reduce the counter to an unsigned type of limited length.

Next is that you are incrementing only one entry at a time. That would allow you to replace the whole array with a dual-ported memory.

*Read an entry from memory, increment the value, write it back the next clock cycle, but check if the next entry has the same index, in which case you do not (yet) write it back.*

Your control logic will be a more complex and thus will need more time to develop and debug, but in the end you should be able to pack the code into something a fraction of the current size. You can also go back to using 31 or even more bits

I must admit, I am not sure what you want to do with the 'number' entry you read out. Also because your 'number' is never reset. You can solve that by running the dual-ported memory at double the clock speed, making it into a four port memory. 
Or you can "in the end" (is there an end?) loop over the memory and read out the 1024 entries one at a time.